Excel shows Filtered data and finds the sum for filtered data without spill error if inserting data into the main table
Excel shows Filtered data and finds the  sum for filtered data without spill error if inserting data into the main table
I need to filter data as shown below using the filter function
=FILTER(Table_it,Table_it[Dept]="it")
And found the sum under it
If I insert data into the main table, as shown in the second graph, I will get a spill error on the filter function.
How can I find the sum automatically under the filtered data, and at the same time can add or remove data to the main table
filter data, sum under it
add data to main table, spill error on filtered data

You could use GROUPBY which includes a total by default:
=GROUPBY(Table2[[Name]:[Dept]],Table2[Sales],SUM,,,,Table2[Dept]="IT")
Or you could stack the sum underneath your filter:
=LET(f,FILTER(Table2,Table2[Dept]="IT"),VSTACK(f,HSTACK("","Total",SUM(DROP(f,,2)))))

This gives a pivot table-like subtotal per department: =LET(c,CHOOSECOLS,c(GROUPBY(c(Table2[[Name]:[Dept]],2,1),Table2[Sales],SUM,,2),2,1,3))

Thank you very much for your quick help
I used
=GROUPBY(Table_G[[#All],[Name]:[Dept]], Table_G[[#All],[Sales]],SUM,3,,,Table_G[Dept]="IT")
OR
=LET(f,VSTACK(Table_it[#Headers],(FILTER(Table_it,Table_it[Dept]="it"))),VSTACK(f,HSTACK("","Total",SUM(DROP(f,,2)))))
is it possible to use the format (Bold font, font size 14) for the sum

It is, but you need to apply conditional formatting to the second column (for the groupby) or third column (for the filter) being blank. The formula by itself cannot include formatting.

How can I add an auto-numbering column before grouped data?

How can I add a signature name after the two last grouped data rows regardless of the number of grouped data rows each time?

@FerasShorafa can you give an example? Not sure what you mean by signature name and two last grouped data rows

i put the function in A1 the results will appear from a1 to e10, i need to enter the name in e12
if the result changed from a1 to e15, i need to enter the name in e17

So VSTACK it underneath, something like: =LET(f,FILTER(Table2,Table2[Dept]="IT"),IF A(VSTACK(f,HSTACK("","Total",SUM(DROP(f,,2))),{"","","","","Signature"}),""))

If you want to stack and calculate more and adjust this dynamically it might be better to switch to vba.

thank you it try =LET(f,FILTER(GBy_T,GBy_T[Dept]="IT"),IF A(VSTACK(f,HSTACK("","Total",SUM(DROP(f,,2))),{"","","","","Signature"}),""))   for sorry I have problem in formula

I had a typo. IF A should be IFNA. Typing this on my phone

is it possible to set inside & outside borders for the results

Borders is also formatting, so yes you can, but you'd need conditional formatting or vba

Use custom conditional formatting something along the lines: for the first column: =A1<>"" (if it is in column A) and select format left border. For the 5th column =A1<>"" (same as first column, to have similar height, or use E1 for both to include borders up to your signature) and select right border here.

thank you i use conditional format for no blanks    is it possible to add an auto-numbering column before grouped data?

Yes, something like =sequence(rows(B1#)-3) if the formula is in B1 minus 3 to exclude the totals row and the 2 below. B1 would then be =LET(f,FILTER(GBy_T,GBy_T[Dept]="IT"),IFNA(VSTACK(f,HSTACK("","Total",SUM(DROP(f,,2))),"",{"","","","","Signature"}),""))
